# maintain the colour of every line in C with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I implement the Worldle game in C using ncurses library. When I added a new word,I color each character depending on the case: Green if the letter is in the same position as in the guessing word, yellow if the letter exists in the word but in a different position or black if the letter is not in the word. After that, I add a new word, previous line takes the color of the  current line. How Can I maintain the colors of every line all the time?

Here is my code to color every caracter:

```
void verificare_cuvant(char cuvant_verificare[10], WINDOW * chenar_verificare, char cuvant_de_ghicit[6], int *castig) {
    int alfabet[127], j, gasit;
    memset(alfabet, 0, sizeof(alfabet));
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(cuvant_de_ghicit); i++) {
        alfabet[cuvant_de_ghicit[i]]++;
    }
    if(strcmp(cuvant_verificare, cuvant_de_ghicit) == 0) {
        start_color();
        init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_GREEN);
        wattron(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wprintw(chenar_verificare, "%s", cuvant_verificare);
        wattroff(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wrefresh(chenar_verificare);
        (*castig) = 1;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (cuvant_verificare[i] == cuvant_de_ghicit[i]) {
                start_color();
                init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_GREEN);
                wattron(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                wprintw(chenar_verificare, "%c", cuvant_verificare[i]);
                wattroff(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                wrefresh(chenar_verificare);
            } else {
                j = 97;
                gasit = 0;
                while (j < 123 && gasit == 0) {
                    if ((char) j == cuvant_verificare[i] && alfabet[j] != 0) {
                        start_color();
                        init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_YELLOW);
                        wattron(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                        wprintw(chenar_verificare, "%c", cuvant_verificare[i]);
                        wattroff(chenar_verificare, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                        wrefresh(chenar_verificare);
                        alfabet[j]--;
                        gasit = 1;
                    } else {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                if (gasit == 0) {

                    wprintw(chenar_verificare, "%c", cuvant_verificare[i]);
                    wrefresh(chenar_verificare);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program fragment is incomplete (the minimal reproducible example referred to in a comment), but it shows two problems:

- **`start_color`** should only be executed once (the [manual](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-start_color) recommends doing this right after **[`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Differences)**)
- there are two different color uses, but only one color pair is initialized (twice: white-on-green and white-on-yellow).  Using a different color pair number would let the curses library maintain the two distinct colors.

The example is clear enough: OP used pair #1 for one purpose, and then changed it to another color combination.  Doing that repaints the lines using the first color combination, according to the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_pair):

> If  the  color-pair was previously initialized, the screen is refreshed
> and all occurrences of that color-pair are changed to the  new  definition.

as well as noted in the [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_color.c#L640):

```c
    /*
     * When a pair's content is changed, replace its colors (if pair was
     * initialized before a screen update is performed replacing original
     * pair colors with the new ones).
     */
```

Using pairs #1 and #2 for example would make those distinct.  For the given example, it is not necessary to initialize additional color pairs.

Comment: not really (it begins with a misinterpretation, which is not corrected in the ensuing discussion).   Regarding the howto, [this page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/howto/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.html) is up-to-date.

Comment: Alright, so, I added an example. Let me know if I got it wrong. Otherwise I’ll delete my comment above and avoid sending people the wrong way. :-)

Comment: I added detail to my answer (yours does not address the problems that I see).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [Thomas Dickey’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924240/2706707) (he’s the guy who makes NCurses things go), here is a simple example.

### First, design the colors of your application!

Many modern terminal emulators support at least the EGA/VGA 16-color gamut. Many still do not.

I recommend designing your application to handle being displayed with smaller color selections than optimal: 2-color, 8-color, and 16-color.

You can query the number of colors you have available to you with the `COLORS` global variable, and you can query the number of ways you can combine them (foreground and background) with the `COLOR_PAIRS` global variable.

### Initialize the colors

Lacking any pretty application design, for this example we will just initialize the color palette to the old EGA/VGA color palette.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool init_EGA_colors(void)
{
  start_color();
  if (   !has_colors()
      or !can_change_color()
      or (COLOR_PAIRS < 256)
      or (COLORS < 16) )
    return false;
  
  // These are the standard 16 EGA/VGA colors
  init_color(  0,    0,    0,    0 );
  init_color(  1,    0,    0,  666 );
  init_color(  2,    0,  666,    0 );
  init_color(  3,    0,  666,  666 );
  init_color(  4,  666,    0,    0 );
  init_color(  5,  666,    0,  666 );
  init_color(  6,  666,  333,    0 );
  init_color(  7,  666,  666,  666 );
  init_color(  8,  333,  333,  333 );
  init_color(  9,  333,  333, 1000 );
  init_color( 10,  333, 1000,  333 );
  init_color( 11,  333, 1000, 1000 );
  init_color( 12, 1000,  333,  333 );
  init_color( 13, 1000,  333, 1000 );
  init_color( 14, 1000, 1000,  333 );
  init_color( 15, 1000, 1000, 1000 );

  // Here we assign all the correct foreground + background combinations
  int pair = 0;
  for   (int b = 0;  b < 16;  b++)
    for (int f = 0;  f < 16;  f++, pair++)
      if (pair != 0)
        init_pair( pair, f , b  );

  return true;
}
```

Let’s add a couple of functions to use the color palette we just created:

```
void set_EGA_color( int attribute )
{
  if      (attribute <  0) attrset( COLOR_PAIR( 0 ) );
  else if (attribute == 0) attrset( COLOR_PAIR( 0 ) | A_INVIS );
  else                     attrset( COLOR_PAIR( attribute ) );
}

void set_EGA_colors( int fg, int bg )
{
  set_EGA_color( (bg << 4) | fg );
}
```

##### Notes

- Color pair `0` is special, and cannot be modified. We jump a couple hoops to do stuff we want to see.
- You may not wish to modify color `0` either, if your user’s terminal defaults to something nice. I have my Windows Terminal set to that pretty “almost black” color and could have left it at that.

### Now initialize NCurses properly and have fun!

Here is an example program that just draws every possible color combination (all the color pairs) in a big square.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Initialization
  setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

  if (   !initscr()
      or !init_EGA_colors() )
  {
    endwin();
    fprintf( stderr, "Failure to initialize NCurses with EGA colors\n" );
    return 1;
  }
  keypad( stdscr, TRUE );

  // Draw something
  for (int b = 0;  b < 16;  b++)
  {
    for (int f = 0;  f < 16;  f++)
    {
      set_EGA_colors( f, b );
      printw( " ■ " );
    }
    set_EGA_color( -1 );
    printw( "\n" );
  }

  // Wait for the user
  set_EGA_color( -1 );
  printw( "Press the ‘ANY’ key..." );
  refresh();
  getch();

  // Finalization
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using WSL2 Ubuntu with:

```
clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c11 a.c `pkg-config --libs ncursesw`
```

Notice that I used the “wide” version of NCurses, which nicely handles printing those fancy UTF-8 sequences.

### Recap

Hopefully that will get you going in managing colors for your application. Remember:

- Design your application palette
- Initialize the palette right after `initscr()`
- Use any scheme you like to draw your components, where you

  1. select the colors
  2. output the text
  3. `wrefresh()`

This was meant only as a simple example. There exist example programs that test the capabilities of NCurses that you can review as well, in addition to the overwhelming amount of documentation.